# Mapster.Tool Code Generation for Specific Project

Tags: c#, console-application, mapster

I have a Visual Studio solution containing various sample console app projects. One of which is MapsterSample where I am trying out Mapster and following the steps described on GitHub https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Mapster.Tool to generate mapping code.

Everything seems fine except for the part where I issue the command:

```
dotnet msbuild -t:Mapster
```

This results in the command executing for every project in the solution even if MapsterSample is selected as Default project in Package Manager Console:

```
SampleSolution\FirstSample\FirstSample.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "Mapster" does not exist in the project.
SampleSolution\SecondSample\SecondSample.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "Mapster" does not exist in the project.
... and so on
```

Is there a way to just execute the command for the MapsterSample project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the project exists within your solution.

Make sure that the name `Mapster` is spelled correctly.

Make sure your terminal is in the correct directory. (ideally you should be in the directory ABOVE the directory the `.csproj` for `Mapster` is in.

Comment: It turns out I need to do a CD .\MapsterSample to jump to the project's folder where I want to generate code. I thought by selecting MapsterSample as default in the Package Manager Console, VS automatically runs commands in the selected projects folder.